# Binding a RelayCommand AND an additional condition

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters, relaycommand

I am trying to bind a RelayCommand's CanExecute in my main window to a child window that possibly does not exist. How should I do it?

Currently I have:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Compact" 
       Command="{Binding Path=CurrentChildViewModel.CompactCommand}"
       IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentChildViewModel.CanExecuteCompactCommand, 
        Converter={StaticResource NullToBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

However this does not seem to work because the converter should work on CurrentChildViewModel (and not the CanExecuteCompactCommand, but I also should include that CanExecuteCompactCommand somehow.

I want the menu item to be enabled only if CurrentChildViewModel != null and CurrentChildViewModel.CanExecuteCompactCommand() returns true.

(reason: the CurrentChildViewModel is a window's ViewModel that can be opened or not, if it is not opened, I want the menu item to be disabled. And if it is opened, I want the Compact command's CanExecute method to check if the compact command can be executed, which is something like at least two items in the listview in the ChildView (Model) are selected.)

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your converter need the instance of `CurrentChildViewModel` then bind to that and not the command (remove `.CanExecuteCompactCommand`)
That said why on earth are you using one command to determine if another command should be able to execute? You should utilize the CanExecute of your command (`CompactCommand`).

---

Ok I think I understand your actual problem now.
If I'm correct then your xaml/bindings work as expected unless either `CurrentChildViewModel` or `CanExecuteCompactCommand` is null. (assuming you remove your converter.)

To solve this you can add `FallbackBalue=false` to your binding, this tells the binding to use `false` when it cannot find the source. And also add `TargetNullValue=false` this tells the binding to use `false` when the source is null (`CompactCommand` in this case)

So it would look like:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentChildViewModel.CanExecuteCompactCommand,
                    FallbackValue=false,
                    TargetNullValue=false}"
```

That said I still would discourage the usage of a command to determine if another command can execute. I would do would do something like this:

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="menuItemWithCommand">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Command" value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
...
<MenuItem Header="_Compact"
          Style="{StaticResource menuItemWithCommand}"
          Command="{Binding Path=CurrentChildViewModel.CompactCommand}" />
...
CompactCommand= new RelayCommand(CompactCommandExecuted, CompactCommandCanExecute);
private void CompactCommandExecuted(obejct obj)
{   // Do your business
}
private bool CompactCommandCanExecute(object obj)
{
    // return true if the command is allowed to be executed; otherwise, false.
}
```

Comment: I only want to call one command but that command is inside the child view model and it is not always opened. So I can only call it when the CurrentChildViewModel is not null.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, you'll need to clarify what you don't understand.

Comment: I have added a line in the question what I really want: I want the menu item to be enabled only if CurrentChildViewModel != null and CurrentChildViewModel.CanExecuteCompactCommand() returns true. You say that CanExecuteCompactCommand should be removed, but it contains some preconditions that are necessary to be able to execute the command. I will add some more text in the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope I understood you correctly, I think I did :)

Comment: I need some time to check and to see what it all means.

Comment: I just checked, but now all menu items are always disabled (also the top level menu items which are always visible).

Comment: Also targetNullValue has not a value assigned in your answer.

Comment: tagetNullValue should be set to false, I've corrected the error in the answer.

Comment: I guess you've used the style I posted in my suggestion of how you should do what you're trying to do. And that style is applied to all `MenuItems` even those that are supposed to not have a command and thus they get disabled. I've added a name to the `Style` and applied it to the `MenuItem` in the answer.

Comment: It works ... actually I also found another answer but I like yours better.